# Custom Guard Authentication Exception

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I created a custom guard (admin) in my application, and everything looks good following this tutorial online (https://pusher.com/tutorials/multiple-authentication-guards-laravel). The only problem is when i try to access a view that is protected by the admin guard, instead of giving me a exception NotAuthenticate, is giving me a "InvalidArgumentException
Route [login] not defined.".

My Dashboard controller custom guard is:

```
 public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:admin');
    }
```

But the strange thing that i cant understand whats going on is that when i add in my web.php routes the "Auth::routes();", it works fine, the Exception NotAuthenticate gets fired.

Is there a reason why my custom only works has expected with i add the Auth::routes() ?

Admin Login Controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Auth;

use Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
     use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/admin/dashboard';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest:admin')->except('logout');
    }

    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validateLogin($request);

        // If the class is using the ThrottlesLogins trait, we can automatically throttle
        // the login attempts for this application. We'll key this by the username and
        // the IP address of the client making these requests into this application.
        if ($this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
            $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);

            return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
        }

        if ($this->attemptLogin($request)) {
            return $this->sendLoginResponse($request);
        }

        // If the login attempt was unsuccessful we will increment the number of attempts
        // to login and redirect the user back to the login form. Of course, when this
        // user surpasses their maximum number of attempts they will get locked out.
        $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);

        return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
    }


   public function showLoginForm()
    {
        return view('admin.auth.login');
    }



    /**
     * Log the user out of the application.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function logout(Request $request)
    {
        $this->guard()->logout();

        $request->session()->invalidate();

        return $this->loggedOut($request) ?: redirect('/admin');
    }

    /**
     * Get the guard to be used during authentication.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\StatefulGuard
     */
    protected function guard()
    {
        return Auth::guard('admin');
    }

}
```

Comment: I faced the same problem. Can you please show your login method. and what controller does the AdminLoginController extends?

Comment: Sure @dexter  , i just updated and added the login controller from admin

Answer (score 0):

Try following the following tutorial, it did the trick for me.

*On a side note:* Avoid modifying the existing controller that laravel ships with, instead extend it and implement your own functionality. This practice will take you the long way.

https://www.codementor.io/okoroaforchukwuemeka/9-tips-to-set-up-multiple-authentication-in-laravel-ak3gtwjvt

Comment: Still gives the same situation, did you try to access a admin private route without being authenticated? What exception gives you?

Comment: Yes, I have created a `AdminLoginController` which extends `LoginController` and I have overwritten `Login` method in AdminLoginController